Pass multiple arguments to single command in custom position xargs
I want execute a command where I have the args as single string but they need to be in a custom position. E.g. in the following example I want the args to be positioned before any fixed args that I have written after the cp comamnd i.e. the path argument /somedir
I want:
echo -n 'file1 file2 file3' | xargs -d ' ' -I{} cp {} /somedir

to behave like:
cp file1 file2 file3 /somedir

but it doesn't...
It also looks like when including the -I{} option, the -d option makes xargs behave differently. It seems like it tries to pass each argument to a separate command call rather than all of them toa single one.
For example, this works:
echo -n 'file1 file2' | xargs -d' ' diff

But this fails
echo -n 'file1 file2' | xargs -d' ' -I{} diff {}

With error:
diff: missing operand after 'file1'
diff: Try 'diff --help' for more information.
diff: missing operand after 'file2'
diff: Try 'diff --help' for more information.

How can I get echo -n 'file1 file2 file3' | xargs -d ' ' -I{} cp {} /somedir to behave as intended

-I implies -x and -L 1. Is something like cp $(echo 'file1' 'file2' 'file3') somedir an option for you?

@WalterA No. The args can be arbitrary, they are passed as a single string separated by spaces.

If this is specifically for the cp and mv commands, this is the reason for the -t option, which allows you to put the destination directory at the front.

"I want execute a command where I have the args as single string" sounds like a variation of https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050, if so the result would be fragile no matter how you try to implement it. Consider how you'd handle it if the args are file names and some of the file names contain spaces.

When the args can be arbitrary, they are passed as a single string separated by spaces, you might use cp ${single_string} /somedir. When filenames with special characters are already embedded in single quotes, this should work.

@WalterA see my comment to @pynexj. I used cp as an example but I need it to work with any command. E.g. a single argument list of files works for cp but won't work for diff which requires 2 separate arguments.

@EdMorton you can assume that args are always delimited by spaces

@Barmar it's not specific I just used cp because it was a simple example. But needs to work for any command

Like this:
$ echo -n 'file1 file2 file3' | xargs -d' ' bash -c 'echo cp "$@" /somedir' _arg0_
cp file1 file2 file3 /somedir

Not sure about your real use case but for the above example, the default xargs behavior would just work fine:
$ echo 'file1 file2 file3' | xargs bash -c 'echo cp "$@" /somedir' _arg0_
cp file1 file2 file3 /somedir


I want it to be split into 3 args. I used cp as an example. But I'm looking for it to work on any command, e.g. diff

ok. updated the answer.

doesn't look like it works :( e.g.
echo -n 'file1.txt file2.txt' | xargs -d' ' bash -c 'diff "$@"' produces error
diff: missing operand after 'file2.txt'
diff: Try 'diff --help' for more information.


@DavidNguyen format is bash -c cmd string arg1 arg2 ... . If you don't include string (_ in answer), arg1 gets eaten

You can use an array for the args
read -a arg <<<"file1 file2 file3"
cp ${arg[@]} /some/dir


When you have the args as single string and separated with spaces, you don't need something special.
Examples:
single_string='file1 file2 file3'
cp ${single_string} /somedir

single_string='file1 file2'
diff ${single_string}

single_string='file_with_$_sign file[2]'
touch ${single_string}
ls -l ${single_string}
rm ${single_string}

